# explaining header files path in c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, header-files

I have a headerpath in a c program that reads

```
#include <lib/a.h>
#include <lib/b.h>
```

How do I specify where 'lib' should be in my makefile? It gives me a compile error saying lib/a.h is not found. But I know the system path where a.h is located. How do I tell my Makefile where to go find lib?

Thanks,
Vik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an argument `-I/path/to/include` to the compilation flags (e.g., `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`) where the path leads to the *parent* directory of the `lib` directory.

Comment: Ok, so dumb of me! I added the path including lib. Thanks! :D

Comment: "to the compilation flags" or simply "to the compiler command line"

Comment: @Cilyan Yes, actually I meant specifically compiler command-line flags, but as the question was about make the way to add flags to the command-lines of the implicit rules for C and C++ compilation is via `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`, respectively.